# top N city per crime for every year

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I have a dataset of cities and the numbers of crimes for those cities for about 20 years: Here is what it looks like:

```
Year   City     Number_of_Crimes
1990   Abville  140
1900   Abzac    103
1990   xxxxx    xxx
1990   xxxxx    xxx
1990   Paris    412
1991   Abville  167
1991   Abzac    113
1991   xxxxx    xxx
1991   xxxxx    xxx
1991   Paris    654
```

What I am looking to have is the 2 cities with the highest number of crimes every year. Something like this :

```
1990   xxxx    512  1
1990   xxxx    503  2
1991   xxxx    683  1
1991   xxxx    680  2
1992   xxxx    987  1
1992   xxxx    983  2
```

Here is what I am doing :

```
 Select Year, City, row_number() over (partition by Number_of_Crimes order by 
 Number_of_Crimes desc) as Ranking from crimes limit 2;
```

But What I am getting is all the data for the every group; So when I limit 2, I only get the top two city from the first year which is 1990. So it looks like something:

```
 Year   City    Number_of_Crimes Ranking
 1990   xxx       1140              1
 1900   xxx       1103              2
```

Comment: postgresql or sqlite?

Comment: Is there a reason that you accepted the latest answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your answer. You should calculate the rank partitioning by year and `order by desc` on `Number_of_Crimes`. It will give you the year wise rank. then you can derive the top two cities by putting where clause on `Ranking`

```
select year, city, Number_of_Crimes
from (
Select year, city, Number_of_Crimes, row_number() over (partition by year order by Number_of_Crimes desc) as Ranking 
from crimes  
 ) tab 
 where Ranking<=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You must partition by year and not by Number_of_Crimes and then select the rows with ranking <= 2:

```
SELECT Year, City, Number_of_Crimes
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY Number_of_Crimes DESC) AS Ranking 
  FROM crimes
) t
WHERE Ranking <= 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=abbe94fceeefdaed1b6ea666f430b6c1).